# FirebaseInstanceId.getInstanceId() failing with SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE on WearOS device connected to iPhone

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, wear-os

WearOS devices connected to an iPhone recently started getting SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE errors when calling FirebaseInstanceId.getInstanceId(). The exact exception is:

```
2018-12-07 14:37:26.529 5093-5093/com.xxxxx.xxxxxx E/OurFirebaseActivity: Could not get Firebase token. Exception: java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
    java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzr.zza(Unknown Source:66)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzr.zza(Unknown Source:79)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzu.then(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.run(Unknown Source:5)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

This doesn't seem to be specific to our app only, when looking at the device logs, this seems to happen for other apps/services as well.

```
2018-12-07 14:02:48.931 891-3870/? I/GCM: Registration for wearable paired to iOS
2018-12-07 14:02:48.956 857-857/? D/AltFCMManager: reading APNS_TOKEN dataitem found a null dataitem: 
2018-12-07 14:02:49.107 857-881/? I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 
2018-12-07 14:02:53.950 891-3870/? W/GCM: Timed out getting APNS token from clockwork
2018-12-07 14:02:53.963 4509-4544/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

All firebase library components are up to date. Also confirmed that GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) returns SUCCESS on these devices.

Maybe a recent Google Play Services update broke FCM on this device combo?

Comment: Getting that as well... :/ Which version of Firebase are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by an issue in the WearOS app for iPhone and Google released a fix in early January 2019 with v3.11.27.